# Why does netty dont send my own POJO over network?

Tags: java, sockets, networking, netty, sslsocketfactory

i try to send the POJO "SecureMessageServerClientMessage" over network to an client. Both are created with the netty-Framework for Async. Socket communications. I am really new to netty, so i take on of the Example code and want to change it, so that it send my POJO over network. I know that is a lot of code but its nearly the sample of them but it dont work .. It would be really nice if some one could tell my why it does not work ..

Here are my classes: Server Main:

```
public final class SecureChatServer {

static final int PORT = Integer.parseInt(System.getProperty("port", "8992"));

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SelfSignedCertificate ssc = new SelfSignedCertificate();
    SslContext sslCtx = SslContextBuilder.forServer(ssc.certificate(), ssc.privateKey()).build();

    EventLoopGroup bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup(1);
    EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
    try {
        ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap();
        b.group(bossGroup, workerGroup)
         .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
         .handler(new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.INFO))
         .childHandler(new SecureChatServerInitializer(sslCtx));

        b.bind(PORT).sync().channel().closeFuture().sync();
    } finally {
        bossGroup.shutdownGracefully();
        workerGroup.shutdownGracefully();
    }
}
```

}

SecureChatServerHandler:

```
public class SecureChatServerHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<SecureMessageServerClientMessage> {

    static final ChannelGroup channels = new DefaultChannelGroup(GlobalEventExecutor.INSTANCE);
    private ArrayList<SecureMessageServerUser> userList = new ArrayList();

    @Override
    public void channelActive(final ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
        // Once session is secured, send a greeting and register the channel to the global channel
        // list so the channel received the messages from others.
        ctx.pipeline().get(SslHandler.class).handshakeFuture().addListener(
                new GenericFutureListener<Future<Channel>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void operationComplete(Future<Channel> future) throws Exception {
                        channels.add(ctx.channel());
                    }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, SecureMessageServerClientMessage msg ) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Nachricht empfangen!");
        System.out.println("Typ: "+msg.getType());
    //Send the received message to all channels but the current one.
        for (Channel c: channels) {
            if (c != ctx.channel()) {
                c.writeAndFlush("[" + ctx.channel().remoteAddress() + "] " + msg + '\n');
            } else {
                c.writeAndFlush("[you] " + msg + '\n');
            }
    }
 }



    @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) {
        cause.printStackTrace();
        ctx.close();
    }
}
```

Initializer (Server):

```
public class SecureChatServerInitializer extends ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel> {

    private final SslContext sslCtx;

    public SecureChatServerInitializer(SslContext sslCtx) {
        this.sslCtx = sslCtx;
    }

    @Override
    public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
        ChannelPipeline pipeline = ch.pipeline();

        // Add SSL handler first to encrypt and decrypt everything.
        // In this example, we use a bogus certificate in the server side
        // and accept any invalid certificates in the client side.
        // You will need something more complicated to identify both
        // and server in the real world.
        pipeline.addLast(sslCtx.newHandler(ch.alloc()));

        // On top of the SSL handler, add the text line codec.
        pipeline.addLast(new DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder(8192, Delimiters.lineDelimiter()));
        pipeline.addLast(new ObjectDecoder(ClassResolvers.cacheDisabled(null)));
        pipeline.addLast(new ObjectEncoder());

        // and then business logic.
        pipeline.addLast(new SecureChatServerHandler());
    }
}
```

Here is the code of my client:

```
public final class SecureChatClient {

    static final String HOST = System.getProperty("host", "127.0.0.1");
    static final int PORT = Integer.parseInt(System.getProperty("port", "8992"));

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // Configure SSL.
        final SslContext sslCtx = SslContextBuilder.forClient().trustManager(InsecureTrustManagerFactory.INSTANCE).build();

        EventLoopGroup group = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        try {
            Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap();
            b.group(group).channel(NioSocketChannel.class).handler(new SecureChatClientInitializer(sslCtx));

            // Start the connection attempt.
            Channel ch = b.connect(HOST, PORT).sync().channel();

            // Read commands from the stdin.
            ChannelFuture lastWriteFuture = null;
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            for (;;) {
                String line = in.readLine();
                if (line == null) {
                    break;
                }
                if("send".equals(line)){
                    System.out.println("Test");
                    lastWriteFuture = ch.writeAndFlush(new SecureMessageServerClientMessage(1, "test"));
                if(lastWriteFuture.isSuccess()){
                    System.out.println("Success");
                }
                }


                // Sends the received line to the server.
                //lastWriteFuture = ch.writeAndFlush(line + "\r\n");
                // If user typed the 'bye' command, wait until the server closes
                // the connection.
                if ("bye".equals(line.toLowerCase())) {
                    ch.closeFuture().sync();
                    break;
                }
            }

            // Wait until all messages are flushed before closing the channel.
            if (lastWriteFuture != null) {
                lastWriteFuture.sync();
            }
        } finally {
            // The connection is closed automatically on shutdown.
            group.shutdownGracefully();
        }
    }
}
```

And here the handler:

```
public class SecureChatClientHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<SecureMessageServerClientMessage> {

    @Override
    public void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, SecureMessageServerClientMessage msg) throws Exception {
        System.err.println(msg);
    }

    @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) {
        cause.printStackTrace();
        ctx.close();
    }
}
```

And at last my POJO:

```
public class SecureMessageServerClientMessage implements Serializable{

    private String message;
    private int type;
    static final int LISTUSER = 0, MESSAGE = 1, LOGOUT = 2, LOGIN = 3;
    private String sender;
    private String empfaenger;
    private ArrayList<SecureMessageServerUser> userList = new ArrayList();


    //Erste MSG, Login am Server
    public SecureMessageServerClientMessage(int type, String sender){
        this.type=type;
        this.sender=sender;
    }

    //Nur für den Clienten, als Anfrage für die user-List
    public SecureMessageServerClientMessage(int type){
        this.type=type;
    }

    //Für MessageTyp 0 - LISTUSER, es wird nur die aktuelle User-Liste übertragen
    public SecureMessageServerClientMessage(int type, ArrayList userList){
        this.userList=userList;
    }

    //Für MessageTyp 1 - MESSAGE Es wird der Empfänger, und die Nachricht übertragen
    public SecureMessageServerClientMessage(int type, String message, String empfaenger, String sender){
        this.type=type;
        this.message=message;
        this.sender=sender;
        this.empfaenger=empfaenger;
    }

    //Für MessageTyp 1 - Msg, die weitergeleitet werden
    public SecureMessageServerClientMessage(int type, String message, String sender){
        this.type=type;
        this.message=message;
        this.sender=sender;
    }

    public String getMessage(){
        return this.message;
    }

    public int getType(){
        return type;
    }

    public String getSender(){
        return this.sender;
    }

    public ArrayList getList() {
        return userList;
    }

    public ArrayList getUserList() {
        return userList;
    }

    public String getEmpfaenger(){
        return this.empfaenger;
    }
}
```

Comment: Side note: don't use a "flat" int as type; java has Enums which provide compile-time checking for exactly that stuff that you solved using int/type. And please specify what **does not work** means. Is there an exception; if so, add the stack trace to your question!

Comment: No, thats my Problem ... if i have an Exceptions i would know where to debug but it send, tell me it success in the "SecureChatClient " but on the Server-Side nothing is shown.

Comment: Bummer. The problem is that your "example" is too big; I guess not many people will be wiling to read through all of that or try to run it on their own. My personal recommendation: run client + server in a debugger to better understand what is going on. Try to remove **anything** that is not related to your base task (sending a POJO) from your code.

Comment: Ok, will do this. Thank you

Comment: add new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.INFO), in your ServerInitializer to check the logs. You can check whether the stuff was sent and received or not using LoggingHandler.

Comment: Also why do you have a DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder in your pipeline?